# How to concatenate the same array 'X' times without VBA using VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create an array that repeats a sequence of numbers 'X' times. Here's what I have so far. (Avoiding VBA).

`=VSTACK(SEQUENCE(C1,1), SEQUENCE(C1,1))`

To which I get:

| Column A | B (times) | C (rows) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |

But how do I repeat `SEQUENCE(C1,1)`  'X' times inside `VSTACK` based on what is inside B2?

I've thought about  `REPT`, but that only works for strings

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula:
`=MAP(SEQUENCE(B1*C1,1,0,1),LAMBDA(a,MOD(a,C1)+1))`

Answer (score 5):

You could use:

```
=tocol(mod(sequence(c1,b1)-1,c1)+1)
```

Comment: Thanks! Very cool, never knew about ```mod()```.

Comment: combination of our two answers - I think, this is the shortest version: `=MOD(SEQUENCE(B1*C1,1,0),C1)+1`